Getting Warning [react-native-gesture-handler] None of the callbacks in the gesture are worklets. - React Native
I am using Drawer navigation in my project and not using gesture handler anywhere in the project just installed it as a supporting library for drawer navigation along with reanimated but I am getting an warning messsage which says that -
 WARN  [react-native-gesture-handler] None of the callbacks in the gesture are worklets. If you wish to run them on the JS thread use '.runOnJS(true)' modifier on the gesture to make this explicit. Otherwise, mark the callbacks as 'worklet' to run them on the UI thread. [Component Stack]

I saw many post related to this error which says that set .runOnJs(true) but I am confused where it is and where I have to change. I am a beginner I have used the drawer navigation before but never got this kind of error.
How to solve this?

Solved this error just by updating all the packages related to gesture handler and drawer navigation. This approach will work only if you are not using gesture handler directly in code. If you are using it then use the worklet documentation - https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/2.x/fundamentals/worklets
